# Char for equality\inequality

Tags: java, char

I have been wondering how and/or if you can use a `char` for equations. And please don't comment *"why wud u want to do that"?*

**Example:**

```
public static void main(String... args) {

    char equalitySign = '<';

    boolean check = 5 equalitySign 10;

}
```

I know the above code won't run(*obvisously*), but I was wondering if there was a similar way of doing so. Or would I just have to use if/switch statements?

**Example 2:**

```
public static void main(String... args) {

    char equalitySign = '<';
    boolean check;

    if (equalitySign == '<' + '=') {
        check = 5 <= 10; 
        System.out.println("is 5 less than or equal to 10, " + check);
    } else if (equalitySign == '<') {
        check = 5 < 10; 
        System.out.println("5 is less than 10, " + check);
    } else if (equalitySign == '>') {
        check = 5 > 10; 
        System.out.println("5 is greater than 10, " + check);
    }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Not directly, but you can build a `String` out of your operands and character operator and then [evaluate it as a mathematical expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form).  I wouldn't really recommend it, but `System.out.println(new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript").eval("5 < 10")); // true`

Comment: @azurefrog Okay, thanks! I check that out.

Comment: This `'<' + '='` is numeric addition and will result in `equalitySign` being compared to the character `y`. It's not string concatenation, and even if it was you wouldn't be able to compare a `String` and a `char`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Oh okay, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Example 2" is the way to go for you. Just use `if-else if` instead of all `if` statements or `switch-case` statements.

**Note** - as pointed out by one of the commenters, you might want to use `String` comparison since one of your operators is "<=" which is more than 1 character. So you will have to stick to using `if-else if` instead of `switch case`.

Comment: Okay, I didn't really want to use `switch-case` anyways. Thanks!

Comment: Could use `'≤'`

Comment: @TomBlodget, are you trying to say that a unicode character for `less than equal to` can be used?

Comment: Yes, if there was an advantage to stay with a `char` then `'≤'` could represent the same concept as `"<="`.

Comment: I see. One of the advantages it might offer is the use of `switch case`. @StarCoder, you might want to know this.

Comment: @VHS What advantage? And know what? I'm familiar with `switch-case`, just would rather not use.

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted, a Map of possible comparisons would work as well.
First, we need an interface to declare a comparison method:

```
interface IntComparator { boolean compare(int left, int right); }
```

Then a map of possible comparisons:

```
Map<String, IntComparator> comparisons = new HashMap<>();
comparisons.put("=", (l, r) -> { return l == r; });
comparisons.put("<", (l, r) -> { return l < r; });
```

now you can just use the comparison you're interested in by looking up the correct Comparator in your map:

```
System.out.println(comparisons.get("=").compare(1, 2));
System.out.println(comparisons.get("<").compare(1, 2));
```

[Example in ideone.com](https://ideone.com/ycupW1)

---

Note: My best days in Java are long over, in C# where primitives are allowed in generics and we have a delegate type, this could be a lot cleaner. I am not sure whether my code is considered good code these days.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to check that out later.

Answer (score 0):

## Using a Map

You could have a map from string operand to bifunction from number and number to boolean.

You could then get the bifunction, with a default function that throws an exception, using the given operand as the key.

You can then invoke the function on the arguments and return the result.

## Example code

*Java 9, but can be Java 8 if the Map creation is changed to not use `Map.of`*

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.BiFunction;

public class Example {
    @FunctionalInterface
    interface Operation extends BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Boolean>{}

    public static final Map<String, Operation> HANDLERS = Map.of(
        ">", (p,q) -> p > q,
        "<", (p,q) -> p < q,
        "<=", (p,q) -> p <= q
    );

    public static boolean evaluate(int first, String operator, int second) {
        final Operation handler = HANDLERS.getOrDefault(operator, (p,q) -> {
                throw new AssertionError("Bad operator: " + operator);
        });
        return handler.apply(first, second);
    }

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        System.out.println(evaluate(1, "<", 3));
        System.out.println(evaluate(3, "<", 1));
        System.out.println(evaluate(1, "<=", 3));
        System.out.println(evaluate(3, "<=", 3));
        System.out.println(evaluate(3, "%", 3));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, Maps are one of the basic data structures which you will need to use. Using HashMaps for caching for example can really speed up code.

Comment: No problem, the bifunction bit is part of the new functional features added in Java 8 (bifunction converts 2 values to 1 value, like > which turns 2 numbers into a boolean).

Answer (score -3):

In fact:

```
char c1 = 'a';
char c2 = 'b';
System.out.println(c1 < c2); // This is print true
```

This is because each char value has a corresponding ASCII value. ASCII values are ints, which are comparable by definition.

ASCII table found here: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't quite what I was looking for.